# modelsim simulation time cycles appear to be different than test_bench

Tags: verilog, simulation, fpga, hdl, modelsim

i have a testbench which states at the top:

```
'timescale 1 ns/ 1 ps
```

a clock which is defined as:

[code in testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSVjz.jpg)

```
always begin
   #5 sys_clk = ~sys_clk;
   #20 clk_in = ~clk_in;
   #8 clk_acq = ~clk_asq;
end
```

run the simulation using a do file:
[vsim in do file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ2QU.jpg)

but the clock period in ModelSim waveform, when measured by the cursor, is:66ns and not 10ns
[clock waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDOpl.jpg)
any idea?

I don't really understand what causes this behavior.

Edit: also, if i run the fallowing commands in the TESTBENCH:

```
initial 
begin
#1 $display("T=0t at time #1",$realtime);
#1 $display("T=0t at time #2",$realtime);
#1 $display("T=0t at time #3",$realtime);
#1 $display("T=0t at time #4",$realtime);
#2 $display("T=0t at time #5",$realtime);
end
```

i get:

```
T=1000 at time #1
T=2000 at time #2
T=3000 at time #3
T=4000 at time #4
T=6000 at time #5
```

I guess this is a clue, but i have no idea what causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have put all the code in text form. You generate clocks following this scheme:

```
always begin
   #5 sys_clk = ~sys_clk;
   #20 clk_in = ~clk_in;
   #8 clk_acq = ~clk_asq;
end
```

So, your clocks are updated every 33 cycles: 5 + 20 + 8, which explains clock period of 66.

An *always* block does not run parallel jobs, nor it restarts till it finishes. So, it will go through all updates before it starts again. As a result all your clocks will have a period of 66 and just will have an offset relative to each other.

Comment: Huge face palm! 
@Serge great answer, thanks!!!!. 
So coming in from VHDL, when i had multiple clocks i wanted to simulate, i would have done something similar, only with 
`code` "clk<= not clk after 5 ns; `code`
Verilog: is there a similar solution? or shoud i do a separeate always clock for each clock?
also, what about the clock ticks? why is it jumping as 1000,2000,3000

Comment: just split the lines into different *always* blocks and the clocks will run in parallel. Do **not** use <= with clocksl

Comment: Yeah that is what i did,.
I understand why using "=" was a mistake, using a sequential operator, was a mistake as you pointed out, but why "<=" a non-blocking operation does not work either, why is that a mistake, as you said, when trying to drive several *parallel* clock signals. seems to me like a non clocking assinment is exacly what i am looking for.

Comment: `=` is correct: `always #5 sys_clk = ~sys_clk; always #20 clk_in = ~clk_in; ...`. If you use `<=` there instead of `=` you cause race condition in sequential logic later on.